# jQuery | Position div related to scrollbar

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, css-position

I'm searching for a jQuery/CSS solution to position a div on the page related to the scrollbar.

When a user is scrolling (horizontally) from left to right the div first must start on `(fixed) left: 30%` and when the user scrolls to the end (right) the div must be at `(fixed) 30%` **from the right**.

While scrolling the div must be progressively animate from left to right..

Comment: have you tried anything yet? we can help if you show us what you've tried so far (a jsfiddle would be the best)

Answer (score 0):

To stay div element fixed use this CSS

```
div{
    position:fixed;
    left:30%;
    top:0;
}
```

If you need a smooth animation in scrolling use this jQuery

http://www.wduffy.co.uk/blog/keep-element-in-view-while-scrolling-using-jquery/